# Cannot resolve method in 'NameStep'

Tags: aws-amplify

I don't know what happened, but all of a sudden the builder is not recognizing the methods. I checked, they are listed in schema.graphql.

I do

```
amplify push
```

but it doesn't work.

I think it started happening after I ran modelgen build.

If I look at the model in

app\src\main\java\com\amplifyframework\datastore\generated\model

the methods are there.

```
Todo todo = Todo.builder().name(0).build();
```

> ```
> Cannot resolve method name in 'NameStep'
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the files in  app\src\main\java, and running modelGen again, a couple times, and it started working again. I am not sure what happened, but this seemed to make it work.